# iOS segue blurs text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, blur

I have a problem. I have created a view with transparent background and a view on center ( message box ):

The box is called iboShadowBox

[image]

In my controller class, i'm adding code for rounded corners of the message box and adding shadow to it.

And at last i'm doing this:

```
self.iboShadowView.center = self.view.center;
```

to center the message box.

And the client says that text is blurred.

i have examined the text with and without setting the center:

With setting center:

[image]

Without setting center:

[image]

Left is without setting center, Right with setting center

[image]

The question is, could setting the view center cause text to blur? And how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

Tried to replace this:

```
self.iboShadowView.center = self.view.center;
```

with this:

```
CGPoint center = self.view.center;
CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
self.iboShadowView.center = CGPointMake(roundf(center.x * scale) / scale, roundf(center.y * scale) / scale);
```

Again shows ping background in debug... ( which means didn't help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that your centre point is causing the text to appear in a non-pixel-aligned position. The effect of this is that your label is rendered with more exaggerated anti-aliasing, hence the slightly more blurry look.

A simple way to check this theory is to run the app in the Simulator and choose **Debug > Color Misaligned Images** from the menu. Rendered graphics that are not pixel-aligned will be highlighted magenta. It might not necessarily be the outer view that is misaligned, it could be any of the leaf views leading to the text, so checking that the frame of the outer view is pixel-aligned might not be sufficient.

A way to fix problems like this is to manually pixel-align the frame, for example with a function like this:

```
CGRect CGRectAlign(CGRect rect)
{
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    return CGRectMake(roundf(rect.origin.x * scale) / scale,
                      roundf(rect.origin.y * scale) / scale,
                      roundf(rect.size.width * scale) / scale,
                      roundf(rect.size.height * scale) / scale);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you'r answer about debuting. Checked my guess:
When i comment out the self.iboShadowView.center = self.view.center;
The text isn't highlighted in pink on emulator. Now i just need to fix it using you'r code

Comment: Could you help me with understanding you'r function? Is this something like Extension method in C#? How to use it, it writes warning: no previous prototype for function...

Comment: The code above is just a C function, you should be able to prepend the `static` keyword to remove the prototype warning. Be aware that aligning your `center` may not pixel align the `frame`, for example if you have a non-even height or width. What is the view's actual frame, have you checked? Pause in the debugger and inspect it or print/log it to the console.